# How to make the Web Page responsive and set refresh rate at the same time?

Tags: html, css

So this is my Meta tag that I'm using in my Web Page. I've tried combining both the content attributes but then the resizing doesn't work. How do I do that simultaneously?

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0.2 'name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"  >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want two separate `<meta />` elements.

A `<meta />` element can take only one of four different forms:

- `<meta charset="utf-8" />`
- `<meta http-equiv="{HTTP Header Name}" content="{Header Value}" />`
- `<meta name="{Metadata Name}" content="{Arbitrary Value}" />`
- `<meta itemprop="{Custom Metadata Name}" content="{Arbitrary Value}" />`

In your case, you want *two* separate `<meta />` elements (though it's a good idea to have `<meta charset />` too).:

```
<head>

    <title>Page title goes here</title>

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.2" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

</head>
```